# Drawing double lines in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, line

I need to draw lines like this in wpf using stroke dash array or something like that. This should represents single line object not two parallel line objects.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can get that kind of vertical line doubling by using a `LinearGradientBrush` for your `Stroke`. Something like this:

```
<Line.Stroke>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.2"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.201"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.799"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.8"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Line.Stroke>
```

You should also set the `Height` and `StrokeThickness` for your line to the same value to make sure the whole gradient shows.

Comment: Yes. You can declare the same thing and assign to the Stroke property in C# too. That's true for a large majority of XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You could draw a thick line with foreground color.
And afterwards, draw a thinner line on top of it using the background color.

Answer (score 0):

you  can draw dashed lines using the "StrokeDashArray" of the "Path" tool.

```
        </Path>
        <Path Data="M21.5,166.25 L360.53687,166.25" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="1" Margin="21.5,175.25,94.463,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" StrokeDashArray="10"  StrokeMiterLimit="9" Stroke="#FF806363">

        </Path>
```